# python regex for group replacements

Tags: python, regex

I have a line that needs to be transformed from weekdays to weekday numbers, i.e. `mon_fri` -> `0_4`. I created a small tool using a dict:

```
line = 'mon_fri'

replacement_dict = {
    'mon': '0', 'tue': '1', 'wed': '2',
    'thu': '3', 'fri': '4', 'sat': '5',
    'sun': '6'
}

for pattern, replacement in replacement_dict.items():
    line = line.replace(pattern, replacement)

print(line)
```

but there is a way to do it via one regular expression using groups. I cannot get my head around named groups in regex; what would be the proper syntax for this?

Comment: Why not `'_'.join([replacement_dict[i] for i in line.split('_')])`

Comment: `regex` is usually not a solution but the part of the problem, avoid it, if you can do that using simpler methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is simple and perfectly clear.  If you for some reason prefer to use a regular expression, here is one way:

```
pattern = "|".join(map(re.escape, replacement_dict))
line = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: replacement_dict[m.group()], line)
```

As a side note, you got the weekday numbers wrong.  There is a standardized way to number weekdays, and there is no reason not to follow it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Answer (score 0):

What you probably wanted to know about the group regex matching is this:

```
line = 'mon_thu'
m = re.search('(?P<first>[a-z]{3})_(?P<second>[a-z]{3})', line)
```

then you print it with

```
print('%s_%s' % (replacement_dict[m.group('first')], replacement_dict[m.group('second')]))
```

Although I find your solution more readable :)